# C++/STL public iterators for deeply nested private data

Tags: c++, class, stl, iterator

Consider the below class definition featuring deeply nested private data.

```
template <typename T, typename U, typename V>
class NestedData {
private:
  typedef std::vector<V> L3;
  typedef std::map<U, L3> L2;
  typedef std::map<T, L2> L1;
  L1 inner_data;
};
```

Suppose we wish to add a public interface to iterate over each of the three levels.  That is, we want to allow the client to build three nested loops that iterate over each value of type V, knowing the associated values of types U and T.  We could add the below methods:

```
L1::const_iterator begin() const { return inner_data.begin(); }
L1::const_iterator end() const { return inner_data.end(); }
```

In this case, the results from the iterator would be pairs, with the right side being referenced to type L2.  Although the reference is `const`, it exposes the full API of the std::map type, which is undesirable for a public interface.  A cleaner solution  would offer only a wrapper to makes it possible to iterate over L2.  However, I have not seen any standard idioms for this kind of encapsulation of STL containers, and even the best case, implementation of a solution seems to create a high degree of code bloat.

What would be a common solution to this issue that plays well with general C++ conventions?

Comment: I'm wondering if maybe you'd want to reconsider your datastructure(s) to make them a bit less "nested"...

Answer (score 2):

Just expose the map itself through `const` getter. Exposing the iterator still binds your users to the underlying datatype, but it's crippling them - for example, they can't use `find` on it - so there is a drawback without any benefit.

If you can redesign your class in such a way that inner map fully becomes an implementation detail, and clients would never need to see it - than you will remove iterators and setters, and expose some meaningful functions instead.

Comment: +1 - Also, by exposing the map via const ref, if your clients are using auto correctly when they iterate, even if your data structure changes their code shouldn't need to.

Comment: Exposing the entire API of the `map`, or even the detail that there is a `map`, is unpreferred for an interface.  I am looking for ways to acheive adequate encapsulation.

Comment: By exposing map iterator, you are exposing the map itself. Don't you see it?

Comment: I do.  I said I do in the original question, and that observation underlies the core purpose of the question.  What is the preferred idiom for exposing the data while encapsulating the particular choice of containers?

Answer (score 0):

I would create a custom iterator that would provide the T, U, V values as you iterate. This would completely insulate your user from the implementation details of your data. If you truly need nested type logic. Then I would use a custom iterator that returned an adapter object that would return the final iterator to the list.